# $f\in L_2(\mathbb{R})$. $\int^\infty_nf^2dx\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f\in L_2(\mathbb{R})$

How to show that:

$\int^\infty_nf^2dx\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Next, I believe this is false for $f\in L_1(\mathbb{R})$. true?

Comment: Use the definition of $f$ being in $L_2(R)$, i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f^2dx < \infty$. This tell you that $f^2$ has to decay faster than $1/x$ when $x\to \infty$ to make the integral finite. Use this to bound the integral $\int_n^\infty f^2 dx$

Comment: @Winther $f^2$ may be unbounded as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre How can it be in $L_2$ then? You have an example?

Comment: @Winther $f=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{an}\chi_{[n,n+2^{-bn}]}$ where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of the set $A$ and $0<a<b/2$.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Very nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\int_n^\infty f^2=\int_0^\infty f^2-\int_0^n f^2,
$$
where everything is well defined because $f\in L^2$. If $f\in L^1$ the result is in general false, since we may have $f\notin L^2$. What would be true is that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_n^\infty f=0$.